# Pause the execution of JavaScript on a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension, and in its content script, there is a call to `fetch()`. I want to get the fetch result before everything. So I want to pause the execution of all other JavaScript on the page and resume it only after the `fetch()` call in the extension is completed. How can I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

I think [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await) is what you need.

```js
(async function () {
  // wait for fetch to complete
  await fetch(...)

  // do something after fetching
})()
```

Comment: It seems not working as expected on this [test](https://codesandbox.io/s/t6cwg?file=/index.ts).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @AdamHan I modified the code a bit https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-voice-g9c6yj?file=/index.ts